# Авторизация в Node.js/Express через Passport.js или Auth0

Tags: node.js, авторизация, password-hash, passport

На вебсайте должна быть авторизация с помощью разный сервисов, как вариант и 2-факторная. Включает в себя по эл.почте со ссылкой регистрации, соц. сети, яндекс, меил.ру, google и другие. Также, смс авторизация.

Опционально длительность сессии, которая устанавливается в профиле, хотя, с токенами можно без нее, как понял. Безопасное хнанение пароля в базе данных, наверное, через `bcrypt`? можно ли с помощью алгоритма `ГОСТ` как-то лучше это сделать? Читал про добавление `salt` к паролю в бд, но нет уверенности, что это лучшее решение.

Использую `Node.js`/`Express.js` и здесь [`Passport.js`](http://www.passportjs.org/) в основном подходит, но есть и [`auth0`](https://auth0.com/) решение - будет ли точно лучше и столь же гибким? Еще вариант - [`casbin`](https://github.com/casbin/node-casbin) , но не совсем понятно, даст ли реально преимущества и простоту.

https://habr.com/ru/company/ruvds/blog/335434/ - хороший материал, но окончательно не могу увидеть наилучший вариант для всей картины.

**Какой шаблон проектирования лучше использовать в коде при выборе стратегии авторизации?**

Comment: Попробуйте задать вопрос на `SO`, видимо в этой части ответа вы не дождетесь.

Comment: @MoloF на stackoverflow? - пробовал. там заблокировали вопрос. у них что ни вопрос, то дубликат или закрыть, до маразма прям, извиянюсь... хотя, кто разбирается - вопрос понятен и ответ в несколько четких предложений.

Comment: Я сам использую Passport.js и настраиваю ручками стратегии которые нужны, но по данному вопросу я хотел бы тоже что-то узнать, может решение auth0 будет более лучшим, хотел бы почитать плюсы и минусы, но уже неделя прошла и ответов нет, даже конкурс небольшой назначил для привлечения внимания, ну никак. Видимо люди разбирающиеся в этом не хотят делиться информацией (к сожалению)...